# Firebase login method error No peer certificate

Tags: firebase-authentication

Firebase authWithPassword() method returning error "There was an exception while connecting to the authentication server: No peer certificate" in Lenovo A6000 with Android 4.4.4 OS version and in other device it is working fine.
Is their any help for me?

Comment: I had this problem and I noticed that the time on my phone was not up to date. Resetting the time corrected this error